# Passing a condition for click in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I saw this line of code someone wrote once that essentially resolves a condition for a selenium click by passing in the webdriver, some soft of boolean condition, and a Timespan to wait for the condition to be fulfilled. It looks like this:

```
_driver.WaitForClick(By.XPath("xpath value"), () =>
 {
      return _driver.IsElementVisible(By.XPath("//div[@class='some value']"));
 }, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
```

What i want to know is how to build the same method. How can i build a custom driver click method like this?  Please help.  New to C#  Can someone share some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement such a method you need to understand several concepts first. I won't be explaining all of them and would request you to search and read.

1. Explicit waits in selenium - [Explicit Waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) . Toggle C# as language of choice.
2. Extension methods in C#
3. Func delegate in C# [Func delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a sample implementation with a slightly modified signature i.e. this implementation doesn't require By.Xpath/By.Id etc as first parameter:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

namespace SeleniumWebAutomation
{
    public class WebElementWait : DefaultWait<IWebElement>
    {       
        public WebElementWait(IWebElement element, TimeSpan timeout) : base(element, new SystemClock())
        {
            this.Timeout = timeout;
            this.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NotFoundException));
        }
    }

    public static class WebDriverExtension
    {
        public static void WaitAndClick(this IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver,IWebElement> condition,TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            IWebElement webElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeSpan).Until(condition);
            webElement.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

You can invoke it as shown below now :

```
 //Wait for element to exist for up to 10 second before performing click operation
    driver.WaitAndClick(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("xpath value")),TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));

 //Wait for element to be visible for up to 5 second before performing click operation   
     driver.WaitAndClick(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("Id")),TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
```

Please note that i have used the inbuilt helper class **ExpectedConditions**
which has several methods such as ElementExists(),ElementIsVisible(),etc. which returns a Func given a locator. If element is not found /not visible respectively in provided examples within specified timeout, exception will be thrown.

Regards,
Nish26

Comment: Rather than having a `TimeSpan` as a parameter, I would suggest that you just use an `int` as seconds. It will make the function calls much cleaner. You generally aren't going to wait for less than a second and you can use a larger number of seconds, if needed. You don't really need to assign the `WebDriverWait()` return into a variable. You can just use `new WebDriverWait(driver, timeSpan).Until(condition).Click();`

Comment: Thank you all. This has helped